# Jquery CSS Background Image rotate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rotation

I have a main div with a background set to it (gear) which is rotating via javascript (scroll). Inside it I have another div (stop-rotate) which I want to stop from rotating. I only want the background to rotate, not the content as well.

How can I stop the 2nd div from rotating? Or is there any easier workaround it?

Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wac3wcg2/1/)

HTML:

```
<body>


 <div class="gear">
     <div class="stop-rotate">
         <h1 style="color:white">random text</h1>
     </div>
 </div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    height: 1000px;
    background: blue;
}

.gear{
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/zZ3fMuh.png");
    width: 101px;
    height: 102px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    var rotation = 0, 
        scrollLoc = $(document).scrollTop();
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var newLoc = $(document).scrollTop();
        var diff = scrollLoc - newLoc;
        rotation += diff, scrollLoc = newLoc;
        var rotationStr = "rotate(" + rotation + "deg)";
        $(".gear").css({
            "-webkit-transform": rotationStr,
            "-moz-transform": rotationStr,
            "transform": rotationStr,
        });
    });
})
```

How can I stop the 2nd div from rotating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the 2nd div rotate in the opposite direction.

```
$(function() {
    var rotation = 0, rotation2=0,
        scrollLoc = $(document).scrollTop();
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var newLoc = $(document).scrollTop();
        var diff = scrollLoc - newLoc;
        rotation += diff, scrollLoc = newLoc;
        rotation2 -= diff, scrollLoc = newLoc;
        var rotationStr = "rotate(" + rotation + "deg)";
        var rotationStr2 = "rotate(" + rotation2 + "deg)";

        $(".gear").css({
            "-webkit-transform": rotationStr,
            "-moz-transform": rotationStr,
            "transform": rotationStr,
        });
        $(".stop-rotate").css({
            "-webkit-transform": rotationStr2,
            "-moz-transform": rotationStr2,
            "transform": rotationStr2,
        });

    });
})
```

Here is JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3xcqjcsr/